# SSRS: When Multi-value Parameter = Select ALL remove filter in Script

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that has multiple multi-value parameter. What I wanted to do is if the parameter is = Select All I'll remove that parameter to my SQL Script. 
Example is I have a Product group and Product Name parameter and what I want is if the user selects all the product group my script will be like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRODUCT_NAME IN (@ProductName)
```

While if the user did not select all Product Group, my script will be like:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRODUCT_NAME IN (@ProductName)
AND PRODUCT_GROUP IN (@ProductGroup)
```

I want to know how Can I detect when multi-value parameter is = Select All. I think it will really help the loading time of the tool if I just remove the filter on my script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot detect when "Select All" has been checked by the user.

To remove the filter completely when the user selects all the choices in a multi-valued parameter you would have to employ logic in your stored procedure that checks to see if all the choices were passed to it in the parameter, and if so, don't use the parameter at all in the main query.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I also have thought of that but I think it will really affect the load time cause there's a lot of data on the list. But I guess theres

Comment: But I guess there's really no easy way on this.

Comment: None that we found.   We just decided to go ahead and build the IN clause even if it's thousands of items long.   We don't find that performance is all that terrible.

Comment: Thanks Tab, I'll start applying it now on my script

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own `ALL` value to the parameter. In the dataset query check if the user have selected 'ALL' if so don't use the parameter.

Something like this:

```
IF ('ALL' IN @ProductGroup)
BEGIN 
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRODUCT_NAME IN (@ProductName)
END
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE PRODUCT_NAME IN (@ProductName)
  AND PRODUCT_GROUP IN (@ProductGroup)
```

It is not tested but should work

Comment: We considered and rejected this idea at our shop because there is no way to remove the "SELECT ALL" that is built into multi-valued parameters.   Having both "SELECT ALL" and "ALL" was confusing to users.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have been thinking on doing this as my last resort. cause If I do this, there's still a Select All on top of "All" and I'm thinking it may confuse the users of the report.

Comment: You are right it could be confusing, if you are disposed to deal with it this will give you the required functionality since even if users select the built-in "select all" option it will use the "ALL" query.

Answer (score 0):

If your parameter is based on a dataset, you can compare the numbers of elements selected in the parameter vs. the number of items in the dataset for the parameter.

```
=IIF(Parameters!AREA.Count = CountRows("Areas"), "ALL", "Some")
```